# Create Django Survey Forms from Frontend

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am developing GoogleSurvey forms like app and I need to have frontend users build surveys. I need little guideline to get started. What I need is to built a view that can generates forms like Django-admin and then same forms could be used at site to collect data from other end users.

Please advise.

Comment: Way too broad to answer here.

Comment: Give me hints I will make sense out of it. Or a snippet at GitHub would be great.

Comment: Do you want a user to select how the form should be generated like one question with 3 options then second question with 5 options and blah blah

Comment: See the google surveys for example. https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a broad question but i will  try to cover as much details as i can.
 form builder class will contain the questions and form_id will be responsible for getting all the questions of the form. So if you want to get all the questions of the form with id=1 then you can easily filter. An alternative would be to create a table just for keeping the track of forms containing only form id and creator and form builder would be just containing the questions.

Storing in the database:

```
class FormBuilder(models.Model):
    form_creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    form_id = models.AutoIncrementField()
    question_text = models.TextField()
    option_types = models.CharField(max_length=30) # drop down or text fields or some other
    options = models.TextField(null=True) # this can be null for text field like answers and for multiple options it can be stored as comma seperated field
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

How to store the responses:

```
class FormResponses(models.Model):
    form_id = models.ForeignKey(FormBuilder)
    responses = models.TextField(null=True) # this follows the same analogies as options in FormBuilder
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

Views:

Couple of things to remember for views:

- You always check that option actually exists which is selected by user.
- User don't fill in more than one surveys.If you want this feature also then you can put one more field in formbuilder to ensure this.

Example:

An example question would look something like this.

Q. How is this going?  #question text
Ans. This is going great #option_type=text and options=null in form builder model
 If it was a choice based question then 
`option_type=choices` and `options=good, excellent, better` comma separated list as string.

In the answer model response is a text field so answers can be put in that.

This is like a psuedo code so you might face syntax errors but this will give you a gist. [This](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder) might be helpful if you don't plan a solution from scratch.

Comment: I tried this way and user can select choices. But when user needs to enter something in the Field as question then I couldn't get it work.

Comment: this is where option types field comes to rescue. This field will distinguish between text field answers and options based answers. But this will put more work on frontend side. @ShaziaNusrat

Comment: can you kindly show me a form example of your give models. I will test it and mark your question if it works. Thanks

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat made a few enhancements for you better understanding

Comment: I am close...I teared down the form-builder app by removing Abstract models and made it a localized app. Now need to figure out a way to present models at front end. Can you give me an example for it? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Presenting models is easy just write the views and send the data to templates they will render and show it to frontend. Also more help than this is out of scope of stackoverflow. If you want you can ask another question because this is getting too broad. Another question for this would help you much more since your problem is large

Comment: Thanks for help and I will try to find a way to tag you for next question.

Comment: Dynamic forms are hell lot difficult to create without react. One should integrate django with react for this purpose